# Yii2 проблема с отображением, messages

Tags: php, yii2, apache2, настройка, i18n

Не могу понять почему у меня на виртуальном сервере так отображаются переводы. 
Запускал проект на Open server. Все ок. apache2.4. php7.0
Запускал проект на apache 2.2. php5.6. вылезли переводы точно так же.

дело явно с настройками либо php либо серва. Кто сталкивался и делал. Подскажите где проблема

Расположил сайт на KVM(ubuntu 16.04), сервер apache2, php7.0. (сборка LAMP)

Содержимое messages/ru

```
'title'=>'Главная страница',
'hello'=>'Приветствую!',
'text'=>'Вы находитесь на главной странице.',
```

];

[image: вот как вылазят переводы]

Answer (score -1):

Проблему решил добавлением в `php.ini`:

```
short_open_tag = on
```